# Why am I getting this 404 error trying to install postgresql 8.2 on centos 6?

Tags: postgresql, centos6, repository, centos6.5

Im trying to install postgresql 8.2 on centos 6 but when i add the repo for it and do a yum upgrade or try to install the package i get the following error

```
yum upgrade
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                            |  14 kB     00:00     
 * base: centos.mirror.netelligent.ca
 * epel: mirrors.rit.edu
 * extras: centos.mirrors.atwab.net
 * updates: centos.mirror.netelligent.ca
base                                                                                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                          | 4.4 MB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                     | 4.4 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                          | 6.3 MB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                                        |  19 kB     00:00     
http://yum.postgresql.org/8.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: pgdg82. Please verify its path and try again
```

When i try to go to this link http://yum.pgrpms.org/8.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml i see a not found page, but if i visit one like http://yum.pgrpms.org/8.2/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml it does show an xml page.

> notice the rhel-5 and rhel-6 change in the urls

So how can i install postgresql 8.2 on centos 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgresql 8.2 is end of life and not supported on CentOS 6 anymore.
There are no packages built for this combination anymore.

So this is not possible unless you find a 3rd party repository that provides it, or package/compile it yourself.

Comment: Yes i had to download the source files from here http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.2.23/ , compile it and add some symlinks so it worked well.